# (Probably) A bug on the links to meta in math.se

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange

In my [recently asked question in math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/is-there-a-point-of-no-hearing-if-two-speaker)

I see this:

[image]

I guess it's a bug.

I see it on the visit meta links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that Jeff solved it by editing the question that produces the bug ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are no longer improperly escaping post titles in that sidebar, so this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, nice to hear.